# Embedding PDF documents into websites

Tags: pdf, browser, web, viewer

I need to embed some PDF documents into a website. The last time I did this, I used a jQuery lightbox to popup an iFrame with the PDF document as the URL. The client's PDF viewer would then take care of the rest.

Apparently though, that was a bit buggy on some other peoples browsers. I guess it was due to the large PDF file sizes and the effort it took for their computers to fire up Adobe.

So I'm after ideas on how to go about this. How do you guys embed your PDF's into websites? Or do you just stick to adding a download link?

Comment: I would recommend sticking with a download or a link that opens in a new window if at all possible.  The irritation to the end user out weight any benefits that might be had from embedding.

Comment: So the 'new window link' would just link direct to the .pdf and let the browser do the rest?

Answer (score 1):

I often use [scribd](http://www.scribd.com/) to solve this issue.

You have to upload your document (can be PDF, DOC or something else) to your scribd account and the service makes it possible to view this (pdf) document in a flash environment (perfectly embedabble with lightbox).

For this solution, a third party service (scribd) is required for your documents, but with their API it's possible to include all scribd functionality in your own website.

Answer (score 0):

We have used [Docuter](http://www.docuter.com)
They let you embed and track

Answer (score 0):

I've used Google Docs in Flash: http://trajctrl.tyblu.ca/?page_id=2 
It's a bit buggy, but I find it works if you wiggle the image a bit - ie: zoom, click, etc. Download link is nearby just in case, too. Not exactly sure how it was done, as its a Wordpress plugin (Google Doc Embedder), but I imagine Google has an API somewhere.